# Script Not Working Problem When We Make Existing Hidden Object Visible [UNITY]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple vehicles in my game. I detect the active vehicle from the database and make it visible in the game. But in this case, a script that I need on the vehicle does not work. What I mean by not working is that the car object appears as null. As far as I researched, the reason is that the vehicle is hidden when the game starts and then becomes visible with SetActive(true).

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me with this problem.

Comment: How are you making it invisible or visible. What I would guess is you disable the game object and then look for it. It will then not be found. Rather than disable the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I start all cars visible. Then I hide all the cars I don't need. In this way, the script in the car I need runs smoothly.

The only problem I had was that a script was disabled because all the cars were visible simultaneously. I activated the disabled script for the visible car.